# LINQ statement generates different query than LinqPad

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code that queries some data via a LEFT JOIN:

```
Model1 db = new Model1();

db.Database.Log = System.Console.Write;

var x = from e in db.Employees
        where e.id == 746
        join f in db.Company on e.CompanyID equals f.ID into fa
        from fr in fa.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
          e.id,
          e.name,
          companyName = fr.name
        };

x.Any(); // to see the query in console
```

The classes used here are generated by Visual Studio Wizards to make sure that the model and DB context code is correct.

When i run that code in LINQpad the SQL query looks like

```
SELECT [t0].[id] AS [id], [t0].[name] AS [name], [t1].[name] AS [companyName]
FROM [Employees] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Company] AS [t1] ON [t0].[CompanyID] = [t1].[ID]
WHERE [t0].[id] = 1615
```

But when i run the code in a simple Console Application i get the following cryptic query that is totally wrong:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[CompanyID] = [Extent2].[ID]) OR (([Extent1].[CompanyID] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[ID] IS NULL))
        WHERE 1615 = [Extent1].[id]
    )) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
```

I tried to find a solution for hours now and LINQ just doesnt get the query right.

Did anybody have the same issue and solved it somehow? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the result wrong too?if yes how? Would you change `x.Any()` to `x.ToList()` and update the sql query in your question afterward

Comment: Are you definitely using the same technologies? I.e. using Linq2Sql in LinqPad but EntityFramework in the console app?

Comment: Remember that LINQ does not generate a foobar. It's all about underlying provider. Check if the EntityFramework/etc is the same. Check if the target database and sql dialect is the same. Check if (...). Otherwise, minor or huge differences happen. Also, second query you pasted is different because it return an effective TRUE/FALSE. This is because you appended ANY() to the end of the query in your code. Yet again remember that LINQ builds the query at the very end, you cannot take a half out of the expression and expect that both halves glued together will look the same as one whole query..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query looks correct to me. The LINQpad query looks different, because in your code you use `Any()`.

Try the following query in LINQpad. It should show the same sql:

```
 (from e in Employees
    where e.id == 746
    join f in Company on e.CompanyID equals f.ID into fa
    from fr in fa.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
      e.id,
      e.name,
      companyName = fr.name
    }).Any()
```

To see the correct query in your console, you could use `ToList()` instead of `Any()`

Comment: Oh my....thank you so much, i didn't realize calling Any() instead of ToList(), how stupid of me. This solves it.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the two are using different underlying providers.  LinqPAD is treating `x` and `x.Any()` as two separate queries - it executes `x` in SQL and executes `x.Any()` in-memory.

Either the compiler or the provider your console app uses creates one `IQueryable`, so you end up with one SQL query.  Note that you should be getting the right *answer*, but the combined SQL query removes items that are not necessary for `Any` like the field names you request.

If you did *other* things with `x` like convert it to a `List` or called `AsEnumerable` I'd bet you'd see roughly the same query from the console app.