# LINQ statement needs to be optimized

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code

```
var x = from e in db.Employees
    where e.id == 746
    join f in db.CoWorker on e.CoWorkerID equals f.ID into fa
    from fr in fa.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
      e.id,
      e.name,
      coWorkerName = fr.FirstName + " " + fr.LastName
    };
```

When i run that code in LINQpad the SQL query looks like

```
SELECT
  [Extent1].[id] AS [id],
  [Extent1].[name] AS [name],
  CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[ID] IS NULL) THEN CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[FirstName] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent2].[LastName] END + N' ' + CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[LastName] IS NULL) THEN N'' ELSE [Extent2].[LastName] END END AS [C1]
FROM  [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CoWorker] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CoWorker] = [Extent2].[ID]
WHERE 1615 = [Extent1].[id]
```

How do i get rid of the CASE WHEN block?

Comment: Do you have evidence that it's a problem? It wouldn't be particularly hard to the concatenation client-side instead, but it would be worth finding out whether it's really an issue first.

Comment: This is amazingly similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500858/linq-statement-generates-different-query-than-linqpad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a query which performs the concatenation client-side instead. As you can see, it's more long-winded - you should *absolutely* check that it makes a significant difference before you decide to embrace it:

```
var dbQuery = from e in db.Employees
              where e.id == 746
              join f in db.CoWorker on e.CoWorkerID equals f.ID into fa
              from fr in fa.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new { e.id, e.name, fr.FirstName, fr.LastName };
var query = dbQuery.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(x => new {
                       x.id,
                       x.name,
                       coWorkerName = x == null 
                           ? ""
                           : x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName
                   });
```

Comment: Ok, this is ugly code. I will leave the query alone :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `coWorkerName = fr.FirstName + " " + fr.LastName` expression, for example by selecting the FirstName and LastName properties separately and perform the concatenation afterwards. This expression causes the problem because concating NULL with anything in SQL yields NULL, but in .net NULL is treated as an empty string.

However, why do you want to do this? Do you have any evidence that there is a problem? The expression is in the projection so it shouldn't have any major impact on the query.